# Is there a need for a configuration xml or drools drl file when using Optaplanner's SolverManager?

Tags: java, spring-boot, constraints, solver, optaplanner

I am using the optaplanner spring boot starter to solve an employee rostering problem. I have 2 classes, Employee and a planning entity Shift. Currently I am assigning shifts to employees based on their skill level using a constraint provider like below.

```
public class ConstraintProvider implements 

    org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintProvider {
        @Override
        public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return new Constraint[]{
                    requiredSkillLevelOfEmployeesForShifts(constraintFactory)
            };
        }

        private Constraint requiredSkillLevelOfEmployeesForShifts(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.from(Shift.class)
                    .groupBy(Shift::getEmployee, sum(Shift::getRequiredSkillLevel))
                    .filter((employee, requiredSkillLevel) -> requiredSkillLevel > employee.getSkillLevel())
                    .penalize("requiredSkillLevelForShifts",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                    (employee, requiredSkillLevel) -> requiredSkillLevel - employee.getSkillLevel());
        }


    }
```

I am passing the list of shifts and employees via JSON to a controller that then solves and returns the best solution.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class RostersController {

        @Autowired
        private SolverManager<Roster, UUID> solverManager;

        @PostMapping("/solve")
        public Roster solve(@RequestBody Roster problem) {
            UUID problemId = UUID.randomUUID();
            // Submit the problem to start solving
            SolverJob<Roster, UUID> solverJob = solverManager.solve(problemId, problem);
            Roster solution;
            try {
                // Wait until the solving ends
                solution = solverJob.getFinalBestSolution();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Solving failed.", e);
            }
            return solution;
        }

    }
```

I want to add another constraint where I limit the amount of a shifts an employee can do in a week and also that an employee cannot do more than one shift a day. Is it possible to do this by adding another constraint or do I need some kind of config .xml file along with a drools .drl file to add more specific constraints ?

Answer (score 2):

DRL (`scoreRules.drl`) and a `ConstraintProvider` are mutually exclusive. You've started implementing your constraints with a `ConstraintProvider` so let's stick with that and add any new constraints you might need there. `ConstraintProvider` is part of the new Constraint Streams API that lets you define constraints in Java and is easy to test using the `ConstraintVerifier`.

If and only if you're not using `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` or `quarkus-optaplanner`, there is a missing piece in your example and that is telling `SolverManager` the class name of your `ConstraintProvider` implementation. You can do that with `solverConfig.xml`. With `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` or `quarkus-optaplanner` this file is deduced automatically:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
  <solutionClass>com.your.domain.Roster</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>com.your.domain.Shift</entityClass>

  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <constraintProviderClass>com.your.domain.ConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
  </scoreDirectorFactory>
</solver>
```

Comment: Does the solverConfig.xml file need to be a spring specific xml file or just a normal xml file ? Also does the SolverManager automatically pick up this config file as I have added it and it doesn't seem to have changed the output of the solved solution ?

Comment: The optaplanner-spring-boot-starter discovers the `ContraintProvider` automatically too, without a `solverConfig.xml`.